# How to know the blocknumber of a transaction hash with web3js?

Tags: solidity, web3js

Its possible to know the blocknumber of a trx hash with web3js or other JS script ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only method is calling the next EtherScan API url:

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash=0xa6db.....